# HTML and CSS and Javascript custom prompt

Tags: javascript, html, css, wysiwyg

Hello I am working on a WYSIWYG editor for my website.

I want to be able to insert images into and that works great with a standard prompt. I want to have a custom prompt that opens up in the middle of the screen instead of the default browser prompt.

On stackoverflow if you click the image button or the insert link button it creates a custom prompt for you to insert the data.

How is this done? Is it even a prompt?

Comment: No, it's just HTML

Comment: It's a `<div>` with some content that appears when a certain event is fired.

Comment: I wonder if you have the knowledge level necessary to construct a WYSIWYG editor without already having the knowledge of how the thing you describe works.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol how is the rest of the page disabled then?

Comment: @user7133318 Yet another `div` that sits between the page content and the dialog content.

Comment: @Ouroborus can you elaborate?

Comment: @user7133318 http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: The thing you are looking for is called 'Modal Box', you can start reading the w3schools page in @Ouroborus's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might work. no javaScript needed for now

```
<div class="Background">
  <img class="CenterImg" "image folder here"> </img>
</div>

and CSS

.Background{
position: fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0; 
right:0; // this is optional since we are using width:100%;
width: 100%;

background-color: #fff;
}

.CenterImg{
Padding: 10px; // top left right bottom to 10px from the corner

width: 200px;
height: 200px; 
}
.CenterImg:active{

 -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: width 2s;

width: 80%;
height: 80%;
}
```

but, if that doesnt work. here's with javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Modal</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to create a modal (dialog box) that is hidden by default.</p>
<p>We use JavaScript to trigger the modal and to display the current image inside the modal when it is clicked on. Also note that we use the value from the image's "alt" attribute as an image caption text inside the modal.</p>

<img id="myImg" src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

hope it works